# custom validation in YII2 rule is not working

Tags: yii, yii2

I have done this in my model:

```
 public function rules() {
    return [         
        [['category_name'], 'required','message' => 'Please enter {attribute}.'],
        [['category_name'], 'string', 'max' => 45],
        [['category_name'], 'safe', 'on' => 'search'],
        ['category_name', 'checkName'],
    ];
}

public function checkName($attribute, $params) { 
       $model = Categories::find()->where('category_name = "' . $this->$attribute . '" AND status != ' . Categories::STATUS_DELETED)->all(); //STATUS_DELETED = 2 constant.
       if (count($model) > 0) {
            $this->addError($attribute,  'Category name is already exists.');
        }

}
```

The problem is that checkName function is not triggering when entering the duplicate value. what could be the possible reason?

Comment: did you check by closing the `)` properly in `Categories::STATUS_DELETED)->all();` ?

Comment: yes it has properly closed.

Comment: You could simply use `unique` validator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok there was a minor issue, actually the table name is categories and model is just category so changing model name to category solved the issue.